# Javascript checkbox + массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, checkbox

Существует N-ое кол-во чекбоксов (checkbox), на каждой странице оно всегда разное. Использую плагин iCheck с GitHub .

С помощью кода:

```
    var itemsbought=[];
    $('.iCheck').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    var v = document.getElementById($(this).attr('value')).innerHTML;
    itemsbought.push(v);
    });

    $('.iCheck').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
    var f = document.getElementById($(this).attr('value')).innerHTML;
    itemsbought.pop(f);
    });

    $('#go-pay-btn').click(function(event){
    $('.gds-buy-items-bought').html('<div class="item">'+itemsbought+'</div>');
    });
```

Я получаю POST'ом в php файл вещи, которые были выделены.
Например: 4 6 9 и 10 вещь выделенная пользователем.

Код отлично работает, но нужно так же и удаление вещи, если пользователь отметил ее галочкой, а затем снял галочку.
Удаление я реализовывал через метод pop, но он удаляет только последний элемент из массива.

Так что если допустим пользователь выбрал 1 2 3 и 4ю вещь , а затем удалил 4 и 3 - то удаление сработает.
Если же он выбрал 1 2 3 и 4 а удалил 2 1 например - тогда удаление сработает неправильно и удалит все равно 4 и 3 вещь, и js будет считать, что он отметил 1 и 2 вещь для себя.

Иными словами, если снимать галочки с checkbox'ов ровно в обратном порядке - все будет работать, т.к. pop удаляет последний элемент, если же в другом порядке - тогда увы, будут удалены не те вещи.

Прошу советов. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Используйте функцию `indexOf()` для поиска значения в массиве. Не работает в IE8- [link](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#indexof-lastindexof)
2. Если функция `indexOf()` вернула значение отличное от `-1`, то такое значение есть в массиве на возвращенной функцией позиции. Тогда удалить этот элемент можно через функцию `splice(номер найденной позиции, 1)` [link](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-splice)

**UPD**
Используйте ассоциативный массив (решение из комментариев). [link](https://learn.javascript.ru/object#%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B)

1. Объявление переменной

   ```
   var itemsbought = {};
   ```
2. Добавление нового элемента в `itemsbought`

   ```
   itemsbought[$(this).attr('value')] = document.getElementById($(this).attr('value')).innerHTML;
   ```
3. Удаление элемента из `itemsbought`

   ```
   delete itemsbought[$(this).attr('value')];
   ```

Comment: indexOf так же не работает. я пытался сделать еще таким методом:   var itemsbought=[];
  $('.iCheck').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  var v = document.getElementById($(this).attr('value')).innerHTML;
  itemsbought.push(v);
  });
  
  $('.iCheck').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
  var f = document.getElementById($(this).attr('value')).innerHTML;
  delete itemsbought[itemsbought.indexOf(f)];
  console.log(itemsbought);
  });
  
  $('#go-pay-btn').click(function(event){
  $('.gds-buy-items-bought').html('<div class="item">'+itemsbought+'</div>');
  });

Comment: p.s в alert( itemsbought.indexOf(f) ); я получаю значение -1.

Comment: @Anonymouse, у вас в массиве что-нибудь вообще есть? А то что-то конструкция `document.getElementById($(this).attr('value')).innerHTML` слишком подозрительная. P.S. Рабочий пример, который потыкать можно в реале есть?

Comment: Конечно есть, я конечно тупенький.. Но не до такой степени :D. http://i.shotnes.com/a/19/rurwtbxp.l0h_55fd91f71c677.png

Comment: Используйте не простой массив, а ассоциативный. В нем на месте индекса ставьте значение из `$(this).attr('value')`, а на месте значения `document.getElementById($(this).attr('value')).innerHTML`. Тогда удалять будете по индексу, он вам известен сразу в функции!

Comment: Как бы странно это от меня не звучало, но я пытался.. Перерыл пол гугла и сотню статей учебников, как построить правильно ассоц. массив. В итоге ничего не вышло. Сейчас буду пробовать еще раз, может что-то упустил.

Comment: @Anonymouse, дополнил ответ. Код работающий с массивом `itemsbought` в другом месте javascript нужно будет изменить, так как теперь это объект.

Comment: Это все конечно очень хорошо, за что вам большое спасибо. Но у меня до сих пор ничего не вышло. Хотя уже близко к концу, все работает, но значение только 1 вытягиваю..

Comment: пришлось извратиться , сделать цикл , чтобы доставать значения из массива, при этом HTML приходится теперь не заменять, а добавлять. Вышло вот так: http://pastebin.com/PJcDjTAk . Спасибо вам большое за помощь, вы мне очень помогли! все работает.

Answer (score 0):

совет 1: **не смешивайте логику и представление**. Пусть у вас будет модель (объект с данными и методами), который заполняется с сервера и отправляется на сервер, когда нужно, а чекбоксы просто вызывают события, не более, при обработке которых вы уже можете решить что делать с моделью - удалить или добавить.

совет 2: **синхронизируйте состояние чекбоксов, вместо того, чтобы реагировать на каждое изменение**. Более того, у вас уже есть модель чекбоксов с синхронизированным состоянием, ведь у каждой HTML формы есть список её элементов, который можно перебирать. Вам остаётся только по событию изменения пробежаться по нему и, проверив свойство `checked`, создать массив выбранных значений. [Вот тут](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp) смотрите пример.

Comment: Я читал ваш ответ в прошлом моем вопросе. Он мне не подходит, checkбоксы у меня реализованы другим способом, checked значения в html форме они вообще не принимают. Я же iCheck использую, говорил же. Без использования iCheck я не смогу пользоваться еще парочкой функций. В общем тут все закручено :(

Comment: вообще, должны. И это плохой плагин, если они этого не делают - выбросьте его. 

Но по сути, можете делать то, о чём я говорю, средствами jquery, получая состояние любым доступным вам способом. Главное - __не реагируйте а синхронизируйте__ и __разделяйте модели и представление__.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var itemsbought={};
    $('.iCheck').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    itemsbought[$(this).attr('value')] = document.getElementById($(this).attr('value')).innerHTML;
    });

    $('.iCheck').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
    delete itemsbought[$(this).attr('value')];
    });

    $('#go-pay-btn').click(function(event){
        for (var i in itemsbought) {
            document.getElementById('gds-buy-items-bought').innerHTML+='<div class="item">'+itemsbought[i]+'</div>';
        }
    });
```